# Weird assembly names in Process Explorer .Net Assemblies Tab

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, process-explorer

I am looking at .Net Framework process in Process Explorer and can see some random named assemblies in the list of loaded .Net Assemblies like p2m1qbui, rhrfmrlb etc. It doesnt show the path assembly loaded from either.

Can someone explain what are those assemplies?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are so-called dynamic assemblies, generated in memory for different purposes. Example, common usage are:

- XML serializers used by `XmlSerializer` for concrete types,
- XSLT compiled queries,
- ASPX pages in case of ASP.NET

You can also create your own dynamic assemblies with use of [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xtysk39%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thx